# What type of faucet supply line connection is this?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, sink

I'm trying to replace a leaking kitchen faucet supply line.  The connection to the faucet is not one I have seen before. See picture. How do I disconnect this old one?  It looks like it either screws on (female) or in (male), but which is it?  It doesn't look like it snaps on or is sweated on. [image: supply line connection type]

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to circle exactly which connection you are talking about?

Comment: If you can identify the faucet, googling for the installation instructions could show you if that comes apart at all, and if so, how.

Answer (score 3):

What you are showing are integral parts of the faucet.  On the ends of two of these are the water supply connections and the third one connects to the spout which appears to be extendable.

If these are leaking you probably cannot change them as they are usually crimped to the valve assembly up inside the faucet.

It's time to get a new one.

Comment: It's possible that this is a push in and twist connection?

Answer (score 1):

So, just dropping this on an old thread because dude above is wrong.

These are m10 thread supply lines. A lot of Chinese faucets are switching to this—especially cheaper ones that are designed for 1 hole.

I know that this is an old thread, but it’s the top one on the search, so someone else may need this answer.

Big box stores don’t carry the replacements, but the pee in a bottle online store does. But, you might be able to fix a leak by replacing the o-rings.